# from_json and decode_json in perl not working as expected

Tags: json, perl

I am having a json like below.

```
$response = {"entries":[{"content":{"eStatus":0,"id":"0","enabled":false,"isOK":false,}}]}
 $responseContent = from_json($response);
```

when i am using from_json or decode_json within my perl code I get following as the converted json.

```
                     'content' => {
                                      'id' => '0',
                                      'esrsVeAddress' => '',
                                      'isOK' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
                                      'enabled' => $VAR1->{'entries'}[0]{'content'}{'isOK'},
                                      'eStatus' => 0
                                    }
```

When value of element is not boolean ( true/false ) conversion happens properly but when its boolean then output is corrupted.

If you will see value of element 'enabled' and 'isOK' both are wrong.

Am i using wrong function 'from_json' or 'decode_json' here.

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

This is the way i am trying to use value of element isOK and enabled.

```
  if (  $isOK = $responseContent->{'entries'}[0]->{'content'}->     {'isOK'} eq "1" ) {
     c4lx_log "value is found to be true and so do some business logic";
 }
 else {
    c4lx_log "value is found to be false and so dont do anything here";
 }
```

NOTE:
Input to fucntion 'from_json' or 'decode_json' is coming from the REST response in format as shown above. I have verified that input is passed correctly and as expected. Its just the conversion that is issue here.

Comment: JSON::PP::Boolean is just an object wrapping 0 (falsy in Perl) and 1 (truthy in Perl). Nothing is being corrupted.

Comment: Why i am seeing value like this                                                              'isOK' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
'enabled' => $VAR1->{'entries'}[0]{'content'}{'isOK'},

Comment: Correct conversion should be like below                                                          'isOK' => false,
 'enabled' => false,

Comment: Because the string `false` is truthy in Perl. JSON.pm creates a wrapper for boolean values so they mean the same thing in Perl as they do in the original JSON. See https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#true-false

Comment: Correct I agree to that. But my question is why i see value as 'bless( do{(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )' instead of false or 1/0. How can i avoid conversion like above.

Comment: depending on value of element 'enabled' and 'isOK' i am writing some business logic if I get value as above after using from_json or decode_json then it does not help me

Comment: hope this clears my question

Comment: You see it because you're using Data::Dumper to dump a Perl data structure that includes objects. Just use the data structure as you normally would instead of dumping it, e.g. `print "isOK" if $data->{content}{isOK};`

Comment: That is what exactly i am doing in actual code. But value of the field "isOK" is not coming as 'false' instead it is coming as "bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )" which is issue here.

Comment: Again my question is original value of field is coming as 'false' but after using from_json or decode_json its value becomes  'bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual code you're using. `print "isOK" if $data->{content}{isOK};` will not return `bless( do{(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' )`.

Comment: This is the code from_json when gets as input this value   --->  {"entries":[{"content":{"eStatus":0,"id":"0","enabled":false,"isOK":false,}}]}... Following output is generated..   'content' => {
                                      'id' => '0',
                                      'esrsVeAddress' => '',
                                      'isOK' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
                                      'enabled' => $VAR1->{'entries'}[0]{'content'}{'isOK'},
                                      'eStatus' => 0
                                    }

Comment: You already showed that. That's just the output from Data::Dumper. Show how you actually *use* the data structure in your code that's giving unexpected results. And please don't include giant blocks of code in comments, [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Change `if (  $isOK = $responseContent->{'entries'}[0]->{'content'}->     {'isOK'} eq "1" ) {` to `if ($responseContent->{'entries'}[0]->{'content'}->     {'isOK'}) {`.

Answer (score 1):

> *If you will see value of element 'enabled' and 'isOK' both are wrong.*

No, they are correct. Both `->{enabled}` and `->{isOK}` are false as in the JSON.

> *How can i avoid conversion like above*

You are actually asking why the module *doesn't* convert the value (to a string or number). That would cause information to be lost. For example, if the conversion you desire would be performed, `encode_json(decode_json($json))` would change the data.

> *What can be done here to make the value as I am expecting [which is] `'content' => { 'id' => '0', 'esrsVeAddress' => '', 'isOK' => false, 'enabled' => false, 'eStatus' => 0 }`*

That's impossible using Data::Dumper. Data::Dumper produces valid Perl code, and that's not valid Perl code. However, you can get close to that by using

```
print(Data::Dumper->Dump(
   [ JSON::false, JSON::true, $responseContent ],
   [qw( $false $true $responseContent )]));
```

It produces the following output:

```
$false = bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
$true = bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' );
$responseContent = {
                     'entries' => [
                                    {
                                      'content' => {
                                                     'id' => '0',
                                                     'eStatus' => 0,
                                                     'enabled' => $false,
                                                     'isOK' => $false
                                                   }
                                    }
                                  ]
                   };
```

> *This is the way i am trying to use value of element `isOK` and `enabled`.*

It's wrong to expect a boolean to have a specific value. Change

```
my $isOK;  
if ($isOK = $responseContent->{'entries'}[0]->{'content'}->{'isOK'} eq "1")
```

to

```
if ($responseContent->{'entries'}[0]->{'content'}->{'isOK'})
```

That can be simplified to

```
if ($responseContent->{entries}[0]{content}{isOK})
```

If you want to store the result for later, use

```
my $isOK = $responseContent->{entries}[0]{content}{isOK};
if ($isOK)
```

Comment: Correct. My question is how can i avoid the conversion here. My code tries to use the value of specific element 'isOK' and 'enabled' to perform some logic. But in current case value does not comes as expected

Comment: also if you will see value of enabled becomes as follows :  'enabled' => $VAR1->{'entries'}[0]{'content'}{'isOK'}.   It refers isOK, this looks strange to me

Comment: All i want is false either remains false or I get 1/0. Some reliable value which I can always rely on to make the logic work

Comment: What can be done here to make the value as I am expecting which is either false or any value which i can always reply on

Comment: example converted json can be like below :                                                 'content' => {
                                      'id' => '0',
                                      'esrsVeAddress' => '',
                                      'isOK' => false,
                                      'enabled' => false,
                                      'eStatus' => 0
                                    }                                                                                        instead of one shown above.

Comment: see I have added an example to show how i am trying to use the value of element

Comment: Updated my answer.